# Laravel eloquent group by hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `users` and `user_positions` table.

**User model**

```
public function positions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserPosition::class);
}
```

**Example data:**

Users:

```
----------------
| id | name    |
----------------
| 1  | Alex    |
| 2  | Nick    |
| 3  | John    |
| 4  | Liam    |
| 5  | Noah    |
| 6  | William |
| 7  | James   |
| 8  | Oliver  |
| 9  | Benjamin|
| 10 | Elijah  |
| 11 | Lucas   |
----------------
```

Users Positions

```
------------------------
|  position  | user_id |
------------------------
| Developer  |   1     |
| Designer   |   2     |
| Teacher    |   1     |
| Singer     |   3     |
| Architect  |   3     |
| Accountant |   4     | 
| Baker      |   2     |
| Actress    |   7     |
| Chef       |   11    |
| Butcher    |   10    |
| Carpenter  |   8     |
| Developer  |   9     |       
| Accountant |   11    |       
| Butcher    |   8     |  
| Singer     |   10    |  
| Carpenter  |   7     |   
| Carpenter  |   1     |   
------------------------
```

In this case how I can group user by position name and get like this result:

```
[
    Developer => [1, 9],
    Designer => [2],
    Teacher => [1],
    Singer => [3, 10],
    Architect => [3],
    Accountant => [4, 11],
    Baker => [2],
    Actress => [7],
    Chef => [11],
    Butcher => [10, 8],
    Carpenter => [8, 7, 1]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a many-to-many relationship. If you use a middle pivot table as per the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) you can reverse the lookup easily.

Right now you have Users have many positions, but you have no structure to easily get all the users in a certain position, as positions are repeated in your secondary table.

If you use the intermediate table you can have Users has Position and Position has Users which gives you your grouping, and also reduces data repetition with Position names.

Answer (score 1):

You can user [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for the same:

```
$data = UsersPosition::selectRaw("position, GROUP_CONCAT('user_id')")
->groupBy('position')
->get();
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = UsersPosition::selectRaw("position, GROUP_CONCAT('user_id')")
                     ->groupBy('position')
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since mysql can't provide you associative array you should use `GROUP_CONCAT` function.
If you have user for example `$user = Auth::user()` and you get `$user->positions` you will get all positions for one user.

If you want to get grouped data for each position you should run folowing code:

```php
UserPosition::query()
    ->selectRaw('
        position,
        GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) as users
    ')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get()
    ->map(function($val){
        $val->users = explode(',', $val->users);
    })
    ->pluck('users', 'position')
    ->toArray();
```

And you rill get array you want

Answer (score 1):

I like Sehdev's answer, but to get your desired keys as well, you could try operating on the resulting Eloquent\Collection.

```
UserPosition::where(...)->get()
    ->groupBy('position')->map(function (array $groupedPositions) {
        return collect($groupedPositions)->pluck('id');
    });
```

This is a little different in that as soon as you call `get()`, you're talking to a Collection object and not a Query\Builder one. That means the subsequent `groupBy()` call is *not* the same one that would otherwise filter-out query results, but instead, nest them. This gives the `map()` method access to all the data it needs to organize it in the fashion you described.